# Solving the limit of $y(n)$ (system of equations)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, limits

I'm in graduate level diff eqs, and I'm trying to understand the correct way to solve this problem. I'm working on solving the limit, and proving that there is a limit by the definition. I would appreciate any help in visualizing this or resources, as I'm trying to really understand what's going on here. Here's my progress:

\begin{align}
y(n)&=\begin{cases}
t+\frac{1}{6n}\\
e^t+\frac{1}{n^2}
\end{cases}\\[10pt]
L&=\begin{cases}
t\\
e^t
\end{cases}
\end{align}

**Prove by definition:**

$$| y(n)-L | = \left| \frac{1}{6n} \right| + \left| \frac{1}{n^2} \right|,\qquad
n=1,2,3,\dotsc$$

$$\frac{n+1}{7n^2}<\epsilon\implies n>\frac{\sqrt{\frac{28 \epsilon+1}{\epsilon^2}}\epsilon+1}{14\epsilon}$$

Was this correct? when solving for $N(\epsilon)$, things got difficult so I figured I messed up. Thank you for the help!

Comment: I made some formatting edits to your post, please make sure I didn't incorrectly interpret anything.  Also, you might find it useful to look at the edit history to see what I did.  In particular, using `\begin{align}...\end{align}` to align equations and `$$...$$` for equations in display mode.  Also, use `|..|` or `\left|...\right|` for absolute values.  `\mid` is a relation symbol, used for things like $\{x\mid x\in \mathbb{R}\}$.  Also, `\begin{cases}...\end{cases}` gives better spacing than `\left\{...\right.`.

Comment: I really appreciate it! I struggled with the latex for 30 min, so I'll look over it.